# How add custom component to Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I have created View stack.Inside that view stack contains canvas.I have developed seperate chart components. I want to load those charts inside view stack on canvas.How can i add chart components to canvas ? Guys do you have any idea ?

```
<mx:VBox left="700" id="group" >

<mx:HBox top="300">
    <s:Button label="Column Chart" click="columnChart(event)"/>
    <s:Button label="Pie Chart" click="pieChart(event)"/>
    <s:Button label="Stacked Chart" click="stackedChart(event)"/>
    <mx:Button label="Bar Chart" click="barChart(event)"/>
</mx:HBox>


<mx:ViewStack id="stack">

    <mx:Canvas id="pie"/>

    <mx:Canvas id="stacked"/>

    <mx:Canvas id="column"/>

    <mx:Canvas id="bar"/>

</mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: In your click method of your button, create an instance of the component and use the canvas's addChild() method.  This is just like you'd create and add any other component in ActionScript.

Comment: I put like this.but it is not working :(

protected function Column():void
   {
    var c:columnChart=new columnChart;
    
    column.addChild(c);
   }

Comment: Quantify "not working"... do you get a compiler error?  Or runtime error?  Or something else?  Possibly there is a problem w/ your columnChart component.

Comment: This is a ViewStack you're working with. If you don't activate 'column', 'pie' will remain the active view, so of course you won't see any elements added to 'column'. (btw: this is Flex 3 code, not flex 4 or flex 4.5 as you tagged it)

Answer (score 1):

The ViewStack control uses the selectedIndex and selectedChild properties to decide which element to display. You would simply add children to your canvases and set the desired selectedIndex (although I would recommend each Canvas having it's own MXML separate component)

```
        [Bindable]
        public var _barData:ArrayCollection =
            new ArrayCollection([{Month: "Jan", Profit: 2000, Expenses: 1500},
            {Month: "Feb", Profit: 1000, Expenses: 200}, {Month: "Mar", Profit: 1500, Expenses: 500}]);

        [Bindable]
        public var _pieData:ArrayCollection =
            new ArrayCollection([{Expense: "Taxes", Amount: 2000}, {Expense: "Rent", Amount: 1000},
            {Expense: "Bills", Amount: 100}, {Expense: "Car", Amount: 450}, {Expense: "Gas", Amount: 100},
            {Expense: "Food", Amount: 200}]);
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox width="640" height="480" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <mx:ButtonBar id="navBar" selectedIndex="0">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:Array>
                <mx:String>Pie Chart</mx:String>
                <mx:String>Bar Chart</mx:String>
            </mx:Array>
        </mx:dataProvider>
    </mx:ButtonBar>
    <mx:ViewStack id="stack" width="100%" height="100%" selectedIndex="{this.navBar.selectedIndex}">

        <mx:Canvas id="pie">
            <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="Pie Chart">
                <mx:PieChart id="pieChart" dataProvider="{_pieData}" showDataTips="true">
                    <mx:series>
                        <mx:PieSeries field="Amount" labelPosition="callout" nameField="Expense" />
                    </mx:series>
                </mx:PieChart>
                <mx:Legend dataProvider="{this.pieChart}" />
            </mx:Panel>
        </mx:Canvas>

        <mx:Canvas id="bar">
            <mx:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="Bar Chart">
                <mx:BarChart id="barChart" dataProvider="{_barData}" showDataTips="true">
                    <mx:verticalAxis>
                        <mx:CategoryAxis dataProvider="{_barData}" categoryField="Month" />
                    </mx:verticalAxis>
                    <mx:series>
                        <mx:BarSeries displayName="Profit" xField="Profit" yField="Month" />
                        <mx:BarSeries displayName="Expenses" xField="Expenses" yField="Month" />
                    </mx:series>
                </mx:BarChart>
                <mx:Legend dataProvider="{this.barChart}" />
            </mx:Panel>
        </mx:Canvas>

    </mx:ViewStack>
</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.this is correct but i'm trying to add charts as seperate custom components to each canvas.

Comment: Do you mean you want to attach children to the canvas instances from the parentDocument? That's not really the intended usage of a view stack. What's the end goal you're trying to achieve? Sounds like maybe you want deferred creation instead: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_04.html